# Dénes Kőnig vs. König's Lemma

Tags: mathematicians, biographical-details

In Hungarian you spell the surname of *Dénes Kőnig* with a double acute accent, whereas [*Lemma von König*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemma_von_K%C3%B6nig) is written in German with an umlaut.  Why the difference? Is the reason behind it purely typographical or is there something deeper?

In particular, if you write a German text, which variants do you use nowadays: *Dénes Kőnig* and *Lemma von König* or something else?

Comment: Gyula Germanized his name into [Julius König](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyula_K%C5%91nig), so [König's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)) it is. His son  Dénes did not, so it is [Kőnig's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig%27s_theorem_(graph_theory)) (or lemma).

Comment: Maybe only the fact that the "double accent" is not present in German... See also [original German pubblication (1927)](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Denes_K%C3%B6nig_-_%C3%9Cber_eine_Schlussweise_aus_dem_Endlichen_ins_Unendliche.png)

Comment: @Just_A_Man "ő" is not a part of a the most common ascii extension, many old softwares has problems to show it correctly. It is not a problem any more since that unicode became common, roughly in the past decade. [Unicode is the standard what enables computers to handle practically all characters of all languages correctly.] Probably that website is generated by some oldie software, or your system has an oldie component.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, in German the Umlaut is often (hand)written like the Hungarian accent, so a confusion is understandable. And the correct character might have been hard to come by.

Answer (score 5):

"ő" exists in Hungarian, it is pronounced as a longer "ö" (and "ö" is pronounced like the first vowel in the English word "dirty"). But in German, only "ö" exists (and it depends on the actual dialect/context, how long is it pronounced).

"König" is originally a German word, and it means "King". His name has German origin, already the "Kőnig" version was a Hungarianized form (it sounds simply more natural for native speakers).

While in the region and the era was/is it common to use some simplification/translation of the names, mostly to adapt better foreign-speaker environments, he and his father lived their entire life in Hungary and they did not need to do that.

The probable reason today to use the "ö"-Form is that "ö" exists in the most common extension of the ascii encoding (so-named "latin1"), but "ő" does not. Another probable reason was that the typewriters and pre-unicode computers of the era could write "ö" far more easily.

In a German text I would use the "ö"-version on decency reason.

Both the English and the German Wikipedia use the Kőnig name.